# dimension of a matrix from a text file

Tags: c

I want to evaluate the dimension of a square matrix in the form

```
-2  2 -3
-1  1  3 
 2  0 -1
```

so in this case n=3, with my code I am able to read the number of all integers but I'd like to stop at the first line and get the first 3 numbers..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int temp;
  int n = 0;

  FILE *file = fopen("matrix","r");

  if(file == NULL){
    printf("Could not open specified file");
    return 1;
  }
  while(fscanf(file,"%d",&temp) == 1){
    n++;
  }  

  fclose(file);

  printf("%d",n);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have over complicated things a bit, but if I had to do it, I would do it this way.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file_in = fopen("mat1", "r");

    char c;
    int temp;
    int n = 0;
    if (file_in)
    {
        // you get the characters one by one and check if
        // if it is an end of line character or EOF
        while ((c = (char)fgetc(file_in)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        {
            // if it wasn't, you put it back to the stream
            ungetc(c, file_in);
            // scan your number
            fscanf(file_in, "%d", &temp);
            n++;
        }

        fclose(file_in);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open specified file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Number of numbers: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this answers your question...
However I think it would be much more simple, (as suggested above) to look at `fgets`. You don't even need to `sscanf` the read line after that because if your matrix IS in fact a square matrix, then simply the number of lines you got will be the dimension of your matrix.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do it line by line, rather than character by character, and while I think it needlessly complicates this particular example, you should be able to see how you could build out from this example.

For example, the `token` variable just sits there uselessly save for the single time it's used as the check for the `while` loop. In reality you could start reading those values in as you come to them, or iterate through the file again a second time, with the exact knowledge of the `rows` and `cols` parameters, so it would then be a simple matter of simply `scanf`'ing the values and verifying the return value to make sure nothing weird went down.

It basically comes down to a tradeoff between time and memory usage, so the decision would probably incorporate another parameter into the ultimate decision, such as deadline constraints.

Either way, I think we can all agree it would have just been easier to require the user to include the row and column counts rather than making us hunt them down.

Hope this helps, good luck!

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH (512)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* inputFilename = (argc == 1) ? "matrix" : argv[argc - 1];

    FILE *inputFile = fopen(inputFilename, "r");

    if (!inputFile){
        printf("Could not open specified file");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char inputBuffer[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    memset(inputBuffer, 0, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH);

    char* separator   = " ";
    char* token       = NULL;

    size_t rows       = 0;
    size_t cols       = 0;
    size_t prev       = 0;

    while (fgets(inputBuffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH - 1, inputFile)) {
        /** Save the current value of columns. I'm checking the number of tokens
         *  in every column because I think it would be a good idea to validate
         *  that the matrix is indeed a rectangle, but I didn't implement that
         *  check here.
         *
         *  In the event that the file has something weird, like a trailing new 
         *  line, this preserved value allows us to backtrack and preserve the 
         *  correct value.
         *
         */
        prev = cols;
        cols = 0;

        ++rows;

        if ((token = strtok(inputBuffer, separator))) {
            ++cols;

            while (token) {
                token = strtok(NULL, separator);

                if (token) {
                    ++cols;
                }
            }
        }

        /** If we reach the end of the line without having found any tokens 
         *  we have probably reached the last new line character before the end 
         *  of the file. Set the 'cols' value to the value of the last actual 
         *  line.
         *
         *  Also remember to correct the 'rows' variable by reducing it by one.
         *
         */
        if (!cols) {
            cols = prev;
            --rows;
        }
    }

    printf("%lu x %lu\n", rows, cols);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```